I/flutter (23170): Input type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'PigeonUserDetails?' in type cast error
I encountered the above error. I have consulted several articles on how to fix it but to no avail. I updated: "flutter pub upgrade firebase_auth and
"flutter pub upgrade firebase_core but still error
enter image description here
Code:
import 'package:chatty/common/entities/entities.dart';
import 'package:chatty/pages/frame/sign_in/index.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

import '../../../common/routes/routes.dart';

class SignInController extends GetxController{
  SignInController();
  final state = SignInState();

  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: [
        'openid'
      ]
  ); 

  Future<void> handleSignIn(String type) async {
    try{ 
      if(type == "phone number"){
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("Bạn đang đăng nhập với SĐT");
        }
      }else if(type == "google"){
        var user = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
        if (user != null){

          final _gAuthentication = await user.authentication;
          final _credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            idToken: _gAuthentication.idToken,
            accessToken: _gAuthentication.accessToken
          );
          
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(_credential);

          String? displayName = user.displayName;
          String email = user.email;
          String id = user.id;
          String photoUrl = user.photoUrl ?? "assets/icons/google.png";
          LoginRequestEntity loginPanelListRequestEntity = LoginRequestEntity();
          loginPanelListRequestEntity.avatar = photoUrl;
          loginPanelListRequestEntity.name = displayName;
          loginPanelListRequestEntity.email = email;
          loginPanelListRequestEntity.open_id = id;
          loginPanelListRequestEntity.type = 2;
          asyncPostAllData();
        }
      }else{
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("Đăng nhập không xác định");
        }
      }
    }catch(e){
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Đăng nhập $e bị lỗi');
      }
    }
  }
  asyncPostAllData(){
    print("Chuyển đến trang tin nhắn");
    Get.offAllNamed(AppRoutes.Message);
  }
}

dependencies:
google_sign_in: ^6.1.5
firebase_core: ^3.6.0
firebase_messaging: ^15.1.3
firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.8.0+8
firebase_auth: ^5.3.1
cloud_firestore: ^5.4.4
firebase_storage: ^12.3.4
Hope everyone can help me fix the above error

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.
